# c++ confusing formula for a random number between x and y

Tags: c++, random, formula

`x + (rand() % y - x + 1)`       this is a formula to find a random number between x and y but I don't know how it was made I want a logical/mathematical explanation for it and thank you in advance.

Comment: It's incorrect, it should be `x + (rand() % (y - x + 1))`.

Comment: Because you've left out parentheses, the formula will produce a value between `1` and `y`.   The `x` terms cancel out.

Comment: Even with corrections, you should avoid this algorithm due to [modulo bias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator).

Answer (score 3):

First, your code should be corrected to `x + (rand() % (y - x + 1))`

The `rand` function generates a pseudo random positive integer between `0` and `RAND_MAX` which is typically implemented by PMMLCG algorithm by Hutchinson. When we assume `RAND_MAX` is large enough, then the occurrence possibilities of any positive integer are the same. And so, when you apply the result to a `mod` operation, let's say, `%n`, then we will have a pseudo random integer in the interval `[0, n-1]`

In your example, `(rand() % (y - x + 1))` generates a pseudo random integer between `[0, y-x]` and when we add `x` on it, we get a pseudo random between `[x, y]`

However, as a supplement, this algorithm has what I would describe as severe problems, the most obvious of which is it relies on the value of `RAND_MAX`. The standard only guarantee that it's a integer not less than `32767`, which is a very small value and so it can contribute to the unevenness of the occurrence possibility of the candidates in the interval.

I suggest you learn to use `<random>` library in C++11:https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I had thought to add "typically", but somehow I forgot... Thanks for pointing out.